# how can i record iphone's built in compass readings and use in my app

Tags: iphone, iphone-3gs

i am developing an application in which i have to record compass reading. which is there in new iPhone 3GS. so i have to record compass reading and use it in my application. I dont want to create my own compass. 
is there any way by which i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I used the code given on apples site but it gives values according to magnetic north. howevr values recorded by this are not matching to values recorded by compass. how to record values accordig to true north.and values recorded are in radians or degrees?